Contagem regressiva em Python usando o for
Boa Tarde meus amigos, estou em um exercício no aprendizado em python em que eu tenho que fazer uma contagem regressiva de 10 a 0 com "FOR" até aí tudo bem consegui certinho, para dar uma melhorada no exercício implementei um audio de uma contagem regressiva com estouros de fogos de artifícios no final, mas toda vez que rodo o código o audio e a contagem regressiva não funcionam em paralelo, já mudei a ordem do código várias vezes e o melhor que eu consegui foi com esse código abaixo em que a contagem para no primeiro número e o audio continua rolando normalmente, se eu apertar o enter a contagem regressa mais um número e o áudio recomeça do 0, alguém sabe me ajudar com isso por favor e se têm a possibilidade de fazer isso com o "for"?
import emoji
from time import sleep
import pygame
p = str(input('Aperte ENTER para iniciar a contagem para o estouro dos fogos de artificios: '))
for c in range(10, 0, -1):
    print(c)
    pygame.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load('ex046.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    input()
    #pygame.event.wait()
    sleep(1)
    print(emoji.emojize('Pow! Pow! 
    Pow!:fireworks::sparkler::fireworks::sparkles::fireworks::sparkles:'))
    sleep(1)
print('FIM! Obrigado por assistir até aqui, até mais, volte sempre')


Não duplique perguntas, é importante ler finalidade do site, e com isso corrigir os problemas da pergunta original. Os comentários foram desativado, se precisar comentar faça na pergunta original.

inicie pygame fora do loop junto com o load do arquivo de audio, deixe só o comando de play dentro do loop, isso ja vai ajudar
